# How to change window icon by invoking winapi in C#

Tags: wpf, winapi, c#-3.0

I am trying to change a window icon using WinApi `SendMessage()`, but with no success.

Any idea what's wrong here?

```
public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
{
    if (!browser.IsDisposed && browser.IsPopup)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher?.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {

                IntPtr handle = browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle();
                string getFavIcon = chromiumWebBrowser.Address.Split('#')[0] + "assets/images/MyPic.png";
                var image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(getFavIcon));
                var bitMap = Utilities.BitmapImage2Bitmap(image);
                //IntPtr imagePtr = image.ge
                SendMessage(handle, WM_SETICON, 0, bitMap.GetHbitmap());
                SendMessage(handle, WM_SETICON, 1, bitMap.GetHbitmap());
            })
        );

    }

}
```

Comment: Most likely, `browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle()` is not returning a **top level window** that has an icon assigned to it, thus you can't set a new icon on it.

Comment: i have got some progress :WM_SETICON was with wrong value and i replace GetHbitmap with GetHicon. Now i have a black icon, Any Idea ?   SendMessage(handle, WM_SETICON, 0, bitMap.GetHicon());

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it works, i got black icon because image not downloaded yet.
the following code is to override icon cefsharp chromium control pop up windows.

```
//ILifeSpanHandler

private const int WM_SETICON = 0x80;
 public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
        {
            if (!browser.IsDisposed && browser.IsPopup)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher?.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                         _handle = browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle();
                        var bitMap = Utilities.BitmapImage2Bitmap(Utilities.FavIcon);
                        SendMessage(_handle, WM_SETICON, 0, bitMap.GetHicon());
                    })
                );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, we need to do all (otherwise, if even one of them is not implemented, it will throw an exception "NotImplementedException") the ILifeSpanHandler like the following:

```
internal class LifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(
        IntPtr hWnd,        // the handle of message reciever window
        int Msg,            // message ID
        int wParam,         // w parameter
        int lParam          // l parameter
    );

    private const int WM_SETICON = 0x80;
    public LifeSpanHandler() { }

    public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return false;
    }

    public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        if (!browser.IsDisposed && browser.IsPopup)
        {
            var handle = browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle();
            Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.feed;
            SendMessage(handle, WM_SETICON, 0, (int)bmp.GetHicon());
        }
    }

    public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, 
        IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, 
        string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, 
        WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, 
        bool userGesture, 
        IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, 
        IBrowserSettings browserSettings, 
        ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        newBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
        newBrowser.Load(targetUrl);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, use the implemented component came from CefSharp, say its defined as "yourBrowser":

```
yourBrowser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler();
```

We need to notice some tips that microsoft Visual Studio mentioned below:

bool LifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopup(WebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, Browser browser, IFrame frame,string targetUrl,string targetFrameName,WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, lPopupFeatures popupFeatures,Windowinfo windowInfo, BrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out lWebBrowser newBrowser)Called before a popup window is created.By default the popup (browser) is created in a new native window.
lf you return true and set newBrowser to not null then an exception will be thrown as creation of the popup (browser) was
cancelled. WinForms -To host the popup (browser) in a TAB/Custom Window see https;//github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wik/General-Usage#winforms---hosting-popup-using-tab-control for an easy method. WPF -For an example of hosting the popup(browser) in a custom window see https:/github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#wpf--hosting-popup-in-new-window-experimental Same can be applied for hosting the popup in a TAB.This method is till EXPERIMENTAL and will lkelyrequire upstream bug fixes in CEF (https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef).
return:
By default the popup (browser) is opened in a new native window.Ifyou return true then creation ofthe popup(browser) iscancelled, no further action will occur. Otherwise return false to allow creation of the popup (browser).

bool LifeSpanHandler.DoClose(WebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, lBrowser browser)
Called when a browser has recieved a request to close.This may result directly from a call to CefBrowserHost:CloseBrowser() orindirectly if the browser is a top-level OS window created byCEFand the user attempts to close the window.This method will becalled after the JavaScript 'onunload' event has been fired.It will not be called for browsers after the associated OS window hasbeen destroyed (for those browsers it is no longer possible to cancel the close). lfCEF created an OS window for the browserreturning false will send an OS close notification to the browser window's top-level owner(e.g.WM_CLOSE on Windows,performClose:.on OS-Xand "delete_event" on Linux).f no OS window exists (window rendering disabled) returning false willcause the browser object to be destroyed immediately.Return true if the browser is parented to another window and that otherwindow needs to receive close notification via some non-standard technique. f an application providesits own top-level windowit should handle OS close notifications by calling CefBrowserHostuCloseBrowser(false) instead of immediately closing (see theexample below). This gives CEF an opportunity to process the 'onbeforeunload event and optionally cancel he close beforeDoClose() is called. The CefLifeSpanHandler:OnBeforeClosel) method will be called immediately before the browser object isdestroyed. The application shouid only exit after OnBeforeClose0 has been called for all existing browsers. f the browserrepresents a modal window and a custom modal loop implementation was provided in CefLifeSpanHander.RunModalJ thiscallback should be used to restore the opener window to a usable state. By way of example consider what should happen duringwindow close when the browser is parented to an application-provided top-level OS window.1. User clicks the window closebutton which sends an OS close notification (e.g. WM_CLOSE on Windows, performClose: on OS-Xand "delete_event" on Linux).2.Application's top-level window receives the close notification and: A Calls CefrowserHosti:CloseBrowser(false). B.Cancels thewindow close.3.JavaScript 'onbeforeunload handler executes and shows the close confirmation dialog (which can be
overridden via CefISDialogHandler:OnBeforeUnloadDialog0).4.User approves the close.5.JavaScript 'onunload' handlerexecutes.6.Application's DoClosel) handler is called. Application wil: A Set a flag to indicate that the next close attempt will beallowed. B.Return false.7.CEF sends an OS close notification.8.Application's top-level windowreceives the OS close notficationand allows the window to close based on the flag from #6B.9.Browser OS window is destroyed.10.Application's
CefLifeSpanHandler;OnBeforeClose0 handler is called and the browser object is destroyed.11.Application exits by callingCefQuitMessageLoop0 ifno other browsers exist.
return:
For default behaviour return false